# Cannot resolve method 'findViewByid(int)

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.equipo_19_sm.prepapp1;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class servicios extends Fragment {


    public servicios() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicios, container, false);

        mainGrid= (GridLayout) findViewByid(R.id.mainGrid);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (finalI == 0) {
                        Intent escolar = new Intent(getActivity(), escolaryarchivo.class);
                        startActivity(escolar);
                    }
                    if (finalI == 1) {
                        Intent biblioteca = new Intent(getActivity(), biblioteca.class);
                        startActivity(biblioteca);
                    }
                    if (finalI == 2){
                        Intent difusion = new Intent(getActivity(), difusioncultural.class);
                        startActivity(difusion);
                    }
                    if (finalI == 3){
                        Intent deportes = new Intent(getActivity(), deportes.class);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega una descripción del problema dentro del cuerpo de la pregunta, te invito a revisar [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los fragments tienes 2 opciones: modificar el `onCreateView` donde el `inflater` sea una vista, y
así poder llamar a `findViewByid`:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicios, container, false);
 mainGrid= (GridLayout) view.findViewByid(R.id.mainGrid);
 return view;
```

La otra opción es agregar el método onViewCreated, después de onCreateView:

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mainGrid= (GridLayout) view.findViewByid(R.id.mainGrid);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Agradezco tu ayuda